# Force textmate to apply a specific format's syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, textmate

I'd like to force HTML syntax highlighting on another extension (one of my colleagues has decided to use a different file naming scheme for his template files).

In other editors where can be manually selected, but Textmate doesn't seem to let me. How can I make these .randomtextension files show up as HTML?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In the bottom part of the window, select "Javascript" as the current language.